# How do you convert a .wav file to .ogg in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, wav, file-conversion, ogg

The program I'm writing uses NAudio to convert a .ogg stereo track to mono.

The problem is NAudio only seems to export as a .wav format.

I can't seem to find a straight forward answer for converting a .wav to .ogg.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: `ffmpeg` definitely can do this conversion

Comment: You need to use an `.ogg` encoder for C#. See which option you like [**from research**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+ogg+encoder).

Comment: I would recommend you use a library like ffmpeg. Ogg is not a fun container format to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
FFMpegArguments
            .FromFileInput("ff067f12-4cec-4540-948b-28fea6d12f91.m4a")
            .OutputToFile("ff067f12-4cec-4540-948b-28fea6d12f91.ogg", true, options => options                    
                .WithConstantRateFactor(21)
                .WithVariableBitrate(4)
                .WithFastStart())
            .ProcessAsynchronously()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).